# Optimizing this MySQL query with a subquery inside

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

For given longitude, latitude and radius I should select the averagePrice, numberOfListings, ... from a database with 500'000 data records.

> (id) 1    (select_type) SIMPLE    (table) database    (partitions) NULL   (type) ALL  (possible_keys) NULL    (key) NULL  (key_len) NULL  (ref) NULL  (rows) 623612   (filtered) 100.00   (Extra) NULL

```
CREATE TABLE `database` (
  `id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bathrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bedrooms` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_capacity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rev_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `hosting_id` (`hosting_id`),
  KEY `price` (`price`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Select Query without grouping.

```
SELECT
   avg(price) as averagePrice,
   count(*) as numberOfListings,
   min(price) as minprice,
   max(price) as maxprice,
   avg(bedrooms) as averagebedrooms,
   avg(bathrooms) as averagebathrooms,
   avg(person_capacity) as averagepc,
   avg(rev_count) as averageReviews,
   avg(time_appartement) as averageDateHasBeenListed  
FROM
   (SELECT
      r.*,
      ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37.774929) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude` )) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`longitude`) ) - radians(-122.419416) ) + sin( radians(37.774929) ) * sin( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude`) ) ) ) ) AS distance        
   FROM
      `database` r       ) r  
WHERE
   distance <= 25 
   AND price >= 10  
ORDER BY
   distance ASC
```

This works well with a query time about 1 sec. Now my next steps will be to group the subquery with the id and select there for every id the average price, bedrooms, bathrooms, person_capacity, rev_count and time_appartement.

```
SELECT
   avg(price) as averagePrice,
   count(*) as numberOfListings,
   min(price) as minprice,
   max(price) as maxprice,
   avg(bedrooms) as averagebedrooms,
   avg(bathrooms) as averagebathrooms,
   avg(person_capacity) as averagepc,
   avg(rev_count) as averageReviews,
   avg(time_appartement) as averageDateHasBeenListed      
FROM
   (SELECT
      id,
      avg(r.price) as price,
      avg(r.bedrooms) as bedrooms,
      avg(r.bathrooms) as bathrooms,
      avg(r.person_capacity) as person_capacity,
      avg(r.rev_count) as rev_count,
      avg(r.time_appartement) as time_appartement,
      ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37.774929) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude` )) ) * cos( radians( ANY_VALUE(`longitude`) ) - radians(-122.419416) ) + sin( radians(37.774929) ) * sin( radians( ANY_VALUE(`latitude`) ) ) ) ) AS distance            
   FROM
      `database` r 
   GROUP BY
      r.id           ) r      
WHERE
   distance <= 25 
   AND price >= 10      
ORDER BY
   distance ASC
```

It works, but the problem is that the time for this query is about 7 sec.

Is it possible to reduce the time?
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Questions about optimisation always require as a minimum CREATE table statements for all relevant tables, and the result of the EXPLAIN

Comment: And please format your queries

Comment: Also, look at constructing a bounding box for filtering geometric data

Comment: I added the CREATE table statements and formatted the queries

Comment: Great. Now for the EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0):

You might move **price** condition to the subquery.

- WHERE r.price >= 10 , if you consider only records with price >= 10 (before calculating average)
- HAVING avg(r.price) >= 10 , if you consider the average price >= 10

Also, make sure you have index on id and price

Answer (score 0):

Your `latitude` and `longitude` worse than useless as `VARCHAR(255)`.  For homes, this should be good:

```
latitude DECIMAL(6,4),
longitude DECIMAL(7,4)
```

What kind of `id` needs to be `VARCHAR(255)`?

Are you expecting millions or billions of bedrooms?  Use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (1 byte, range of 0..255) for more efficiency.

There is no `PRIMARY KEY`; that is bad for InnoDB.

AVG(AVG(...)) is mathematically bad.

Your subquery implies that there are multiple rows with the same `id`; what is going on?

Fix those things, read about ["bounding boxes"](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql), then come back for more help/abuse.